# Modify Search Result Items to Open Directly to Result Location

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results

I'm in charge of a knowledge base and have been asked if it's possible to modify SP search results such that when a user clicks on an item containing the search phrase, that item opens directly to the location of the phrase.

For example, say a user searches for the phrase "cake decorating" and finds several lengthy articles in which "cake decorating" appears – but not until deep in the article body. The user would essentially have to perform a second search using the browser's find function to locate the exact phrase. Would it be possible to modify how the results function such that when the user clicks on one of the result articles, the article opens to/scrolls to where the phrase "cake decorating" is located?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Online or on-premises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think that is possible.

What you are trying to achieve is beyond SharePoint’s ability. Also, as far as I know, there is no way you can read the keyword from outside a file (word document) and add a link to that.